# For loop opening urls

Tags: javascript, url, loops, for-loop

I am using a for loop to open several urls, however it only opens the first item in the array. I have tried with a for ( i in array) but it came up with the same result.

```
    <HTML>

<HEAD>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

function launchproducts (form) {

var input_from_user = form.inputbox.value;

var product_numbers;

product_numbers = input_from_user.split(";",100000);


for ( var i = 0; i < product_numbers.length; i++) {
     launch_code = "http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + product_numbers[i];

 window.open(launch_code, '_blank');

    }
}
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<FORM NAME="myform" ACTION="" METHOD="GET">Enter product numbers: <BR>
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="inputbox" VALUE=""><P>
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button" Value="Click" onClick="launchproducts(this.form)">
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Works for me when I enter semicolon separated data. explain what should happen?

Comment: Id doesnt seem to work in Chrome, is there a way to make it do so or is it a setting that needs changing.

Comment: In my case, Chrome is blocking it as a pop-up, but works otherwise!!

Comment: I just spent an hour with the same issue and turns out it was the pop-up blocker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function launchproducts (form) {
var input_from_user = form.inputbox.value;
var product_numbers;
product_numbers = input_from_user.split(";",100000);
for ( var i = 0; i < product_numbers.length; i++) {
     var launch_code = "http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + product_numbers[i];
     var go = confirm("Launch next ? (" + product_numbers[i] + ")");
     if (go) {
         window.open(launch_code, '_blank');
     }
  }
}
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<FORM NAME="myform" ACTION="" METHOD="GET">Enter product numbers: <BR>
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="inputbox" VALUE=""><P>
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button" Value="Click" onClick="launchproducts(this.form)">
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```